# A simple method for disabling WPML language switcher when meeting specific circumstances

Tags: conditional-tags, multi-language, plugin-wpml

this is not a question but -hopefully- an answer. I realized that more than a couple of people on the WPML forum asked for a solution to this matter, so I thought it could be useful to share my workaround here as I did there.

**The Issue**

Let's say that for whatever reason you need to disable the WPML language switcher *just for a specific page*, or even for all posts, or all single pages in a category... literally for *any* reason.

For example I have a menu **M1** in position **m-1** with **Home | about us | contact us**, and with the switcher **SW1** assigned to it via the *WPML > languages* page; let's say that I don't want **SW1** to appear when I'm in the **about us** page.

**The workaround**

I just register another menu **M2** -which is the exact copy of M1- and assign it to position **m-2**.

*At this point I already have total control in my template files upon where and when SW1 will appear*, using WordPress conditional tags or whatever other PHP condition.

For example in `page.php` I can do:

```
if ( is_page( 'about-us' ) ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'm-2', (...etc) ) );
} else {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'm-1', (...etc) ) );
}
```

Now **SW1** will appear only when we are not in the *about us* page since it's assigned to **m-1** and *about us* picks **m-2**.

**Trivia**

I had to found this workaround because WPML had problems with CPT date archives and I needed a fast idea. More specifically, if I had, say, "mysite.com/it/mia-pagina/2020/" I couldn't find a way to go to "mysite.com/en/my-page/2020/" via the default switcher (N.B. I had already enabled the date archives for CPTs thanks to a third party plugin that just adds the rewrite rules that in WordPress are missing for this scenario).

Funny enough, I could go to the desired page if I just manually wrote its url in the browser. It's just that the WPML switcher's link failed in this specific case.

So without the time to wait for a core update or for a deep and slow programming, I needed to disable the default WPML language switcher just for CPT date archives and substitute it with a custom one.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry for the rough incipit but for some reason this editor strips out my initial "Hello everyone". I've tried like 200 times, I give up.

Comment: This isn't a Discussion forum, but a Q&A site. You can post a question and then post its answer below, otherwise the question is marked as unanswered. Unfortunately WPML as a 3rd party plugin is offtopic here

Comment: Hello Tom, thanks for your intervention, I've been inattentive on this site's purpose.
I guess I could edit the post as a Q&A section, if you don't mind: I still think that the solution being a WordPress only one, it could fit well in this site. But of course I'll wait for a final "yes" (I'll edit the post) or "no" (I'll delete it) from you.

Comment: There are only questions and answers here, that's what stackoverflow and the stack exchange sites are. Since the question is closed there is no need to delete it